# How do I do a text-only compare between git branches in Eclipse (with EGit)

Tags: java, eclipse, git, comparison, egit

Every comparison operation that I use seems to also compare the commits to each other, so that some of the differences highlighted are textually (including whitespace) identical but different because they come from commits that aren't cherry-pick related to each other.

Is there a setting that I can change so that commit-only differences are ignored and only textual differences are shown?

Operations that show commit-only differences:

1. Go to the Java View
   Right click on a file
   "Compare With" --> "Branch, Tag or Reference.."
   Select a branch, tag or reference
   Some of the differences shown are commit-only
2. Go to the Java View
   Right click on a directory
   "Compare With" --> "Branch, Tag or Reference.."
   Select a branch, tag or reference
   Eclipse switches to the "Synchronize" view
   Some of the differences shown are commit-only

I'm using Mars Milestone 2 (4.5.0M2) with Egit 3.4.0 but have experienced this problem since Kepler (4.3) with Egit 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be an issue with permission type. Git stores the execute permission of files. However, in Windows, this can get messed up because Windows does not integrate with Git well regarding this issue.

Do

```
git cat-file -p <commit-id>:<path>/<to>/<directory>
```

of the directory containing a file that you are finding differences. See if there are discrepancies between the two commits for the permission column (the first value listed on each file's line in the tree object)

100644 indicates non-executable
100755 indicates executable.

Git has only two permission types.